# Physics simulator to test the properties of metal alloys

Tags: material-science, simulations

In my free time I enjoy designing and invent random devices that do a variety of things and as part of this I design the materials that would be used to make the object, taking into account the needs of the machine and creating a material that would be suitable for the task.

Frequently I have researched metallic alloys that I believe may be suitable for the device, however if they are not typically made and used I struggle to find information on the particular alloy composition that I have imagined.

Is there a program/resource available that would allow me to input the composition of a material and the program will simulate what would happen under standard conditions and can tell me information about it?

(For example if I were to put in the ingredients about carbon-steel and then throw in some gadolinium or manganese, I would like to see how that would affect the resultant material.)

I'm not a materials engineer so I basically just have to guess what it might do and if it would be suitable. It would be handy to have some way to actually get an accurate answer.

Comment: Metallurgy is a complex art. Properties depend on heat treatment and on microstructure, not just on composition. Sometimes, Miedema's model of binary alloys may help, but you need to know what you are doing.

Comment: Or the CALPHAD (Calculation of Phase Diagrams) approaches may help, but if the phase diagram data is not there you are not going to get too far. And even then transitioning from bulk phase properties to performance of an engineered material is fraught with peril...

Comment: I too am interested in an answer to this - I am working on a couple of space-oriented projects from a "clean sheet," including the engines and such, and I'd like to see about designing new refractory alloys (my opposite number on one has an idea for a new process that, if it does what we want it to, will build the engine in a manner almost like nanotechnology.  He's just not sure if he can deposit alloys doing it.)

The catch?  Can't use non-metal elements.  Most refractory alloys are listing trace non-metals.  What happens if they're eliminated?  That's what I need to find out.